# Are people more likely to use words they've heard recently in conversation?

Tags: language, linguistics, language-processing, priming, psycholinguistics

I have noticed before that if I use a somewhat uncommon word like "doubtlessly" in conversation, my conversation partner is more likely to say the word again later.
Am I falling prey to a [frequency illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_illusion) or is this a real phenomenon?
I would be interested if anyone knows any research or studies on this subject.

Comment: I think [mirroring](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirroring#:~:text=Mirroring%20is%20the%20behavior%20in,of%20close%20friends%20or%20family.) is relevant, here.